# What is the tar-data.json.gz in /var/lib/docker/graph/<image GUID>

Tags: docker

I use the Docker 1.8.3. The `/var/lib/docker/repositories-aufs` stores the local images information matching the output of `# docker images`. The `/var/lib/docker/graph/<image GUID>` maintain metadata and so on for each images.

The `json` holds metadata about the image.

The `layersize` indicates the size of the layer.

And what is the `tar-data.json.gz` and `v1Compatibility`?

```
# ll /var/lib/docker/graph/ca0ef69
drwx------   2 root root  4096 10月 29 12:08 ./
drwx------ 150 root root 20480 11月  1 12:29 ../
-rw-------   1 root root  1384 10月 29 12:06 json
-rw-------   1 root root     1 10月 29 12:06 layersize
-rw-------   1 root root    82 10月 29 12:06 tar-data.json.gz
-rw-------   1 root root  1384 10月 29 12:08 v1Compatibility
```

Answer (score 1):

`tar-data.json.gz` stores the image layer:
This seems to have been introduced in docker 1.8 by [PR 14067](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/14067).

> This pull request introduces a library (vbatts/tar-split) that is for inline disassembly of TAR archives.
>   The disassembly does not do any extraction, but preserves the raw bytes of headers and padding from the archive, and defers the extraction. This way validation and extraction continue to be a lockstep process.
>
> For an docker pull, docker load or docker commit after this feature, there will be a new state file stored for the image layer (e.g. `/var/lib/docker/graph/<ID>/tar-data.json.gz`).
>
> For existing images that do not have this new state file, the tar archive produced by docker save or docker push will fallback to the traditional `graphdriver.Diff` as they have been.
>
> The benefit of this feature is that rather than hoping the `graph.TarLayer` produced is deterministic, the tar archive will be reassembled from the raw bytes of the original archive.
>
> Presently the issue exists that an image pulled from a repo like the Docker hub, and then pushed to a local registry may likely have a new digests.

---

`v1compatibility` was introduced in docker 1.3 ([commit 15d5c7f](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/15d5c7f10f56faeaa04f6374341e1cfd3e03cab1)), but is used only with docker 1.8 ([commit 745820f](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/745820fec0faba80b1e0df9c236c6181930647db)) in [`manifest.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/745820fec0faba80b1e0df9c236c6181930647db/vendor/src/github.com/docker/distribution/manifest/manifest.go#L120-L124)

```
// History stores unstructured v1 compatibility information
type History struct {
    // V1Compatibility is the raw v1 compatibility information
    V1Compatibility string `json:"v1Compatibility"`
}
```

And *really* used in docker 1.9 ([commit 504e67b](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/504e67b867865a2835e8002c01087a2cfd7bfd0e)) in [`graph/graph.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/504e67b867865a2835e8002c01087a2cfd7bfd0e/graph/graph.go#L601-L608), where the `v1Compatibility` JSON data associated
with the image in the manifest is stored to the disk.
Then [`graph/pull_v2.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/504e67b867865a2835e8002c01087a2cfd7bfd0e/graph/pull_v2.go#L594-L614), when attempting a tag reuse, can check for its compatibility.
You can see it used in [`graph/pull_v2_test.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/504e67b867865a2835e8002c01087a2cfd7bfd0e/graph/pull_v2_test.go).

Comment: So the `tar-data.json.gz` store the image layer.

Comment: How about the `v1Compatibility`?

Comment: @firelyu I have edited the answer to include `v1Compatibility`.